# Subscribe private calendar by iOS and Android with authentication

Tags: android, ios, calendar

Please suggest a backend and mobile solution to enable the schedule of events and activites for each users in our backend system to be synchronized to users' iOS and Android device calendar.  Due to privacy issue, authentication is requried for subscribing the user's own calendar from mobile device.  The schedule of events in mobile client should not be editable.  Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what your system is. All WebCal/WebDAV solutions I know would fit that description. From your tags, the server part shall be available for Android and iOS – is that correct? If not, please [edit] your question and fill that gap.

Comment: @https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/185/izzy, questions has been updated.  Actually the backend calendar service is not available now.  We need to setup one which suits our needs.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update (and `@izzy` suffices for a ping :) I'd use something based on CalDAV. There are good clients for Android (DAVDroid, now named DAVx5 is what I use and am happy with). Cannot tell for iOS though.